# Is there better way of writing these IF checks?

Tags: c#

This is what I have, But I think I can write it in a sohrter and more efficient way too, what do you suggest?

```
    string actionString= string.Empty;

    if (auditAction == DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum.Save)
    {
        actionString = Properties.Resources.SAVE_ACTION_MESSAGE;
    }

    if (auditAction == DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum.Complete && model.Dirty) 
    {
        actionString = "Save'NComplete";
    }
    else if(auditAction == DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum.Complete)
    {
        actionString = "OnlyComplete.";
    }
```

**EDIT: Ok I changed it a little bit, better now?**

```
    string actionString= string.Empty;

    if (auditAction == DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum.Save)
    {
        actionString = Properties.Resources.SAVE_ACTION_MESSAGE;
    }
    else if (auditAction == DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum.Complete ) 
    {
        if (model.Dirty)
        {
            actionString = "Save'NComplete";
        }
        else
        {
            actionString = "OnlyComplete";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really don't like the nested 'if' in the 'else if'.  I would go with the method solution below.

Comment: I'm not very fond of switches... how about a stack ternary operators? XD

Comment: As @Omega suggested perhaps if not the switch then you could also look at the ternary I used for dirty part i.e. actionString = model.IsDirty ? "Save'NComplete" : "OnlyComplete" to further shorten it if you wanted

Comment: I am not that fond of enums, they always mess the code with if's, switches. Can't you specialize your class and move this logic in each specialized class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a switch?  Although whether it's shorter or more efficient or even easier to read up for debate.

```
string actionString = GetStatusMessage(auditAction);

// ...
function GetStatusMessage(DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum status) 
{
   switch(status)
   {
      case DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum.Save:
           return Properties.Resources.SAVE_ACTION_MESSAGE;
      case DSRHelper.SaveStatusEnum.Complete:
           return model.Dirty ? "Save'NComplete" : "OnlyComplete.";
      default:
           return string.Empty;
   }
}
```

Comment: I was 80% typing this exact same answer.  One thing though, you might have to pass in the model object to the GetStatusMessage method.

Comment: @JeffVanzella yeah I thought about that after I wrote it and then figured I'd wait until the OP stated that it wasn't a class level variable.  Just another way to skin this cat :)